# Структуры в с++

Tags: c++, структуры

[image: Неправильно выводит в таблице дату рождения и телефон, а так же выводит данные по запросу фамилии]

## Описать структуру с именем NOTE2, содержащую поля: Name – фамилия и инициалы, TELE – номер телефона, DATE – дата рождения (год, месяц, число).

Написать программу, выполняющую:

- ввод с клавиатуры данных в массив BLOCK2, состоящий из 7 элементов типа NOTE1, записи должны быть упорядочены по фамилиям в алфавитном порядке;
- вывод на экран информации о человеке, чья фамилия введена с клавиатуры;
- если такого нет – выдать сообщение.

Неправильно выводит в таблице дату рождения и телефон, а так же выводит неверные данные по запросу фамилии после таблицы.

Подскажите в чем ошибка?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#define M 15
#define N 7
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)// чтобы компилятор не ругался на strcpy

using namespace std;

struct NOTE2
{
    char name[M];
    int num;
    char date[M];
};

int main()
{

    setlocale(0, "rus");

    NOTE2 BLOCK2[N];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        cout << "\nВведите имя: ";
        cin >> BLOCK2[i].name;
        cout << "\nВведите номер телефона: ";
        cin >> BLOCK2[i].num;
        cout << "\nВведите дату рождения: ";
        cin >> BLOCK2[i].date;
    }
    char cur[M];
    for (i = 0; i<N - 1; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j<N; j++)
            if (strcmp(BLOCK2[i].name, BLOCK2[j].name)>0)
            {
                strcpy(cur, BLOCK2[i].name);
                strcpy(BLOCK2[i].name, BLOCK2[j].name);
                strcpy(BLOCK2[j].name, cur);
            }
    cout << "\n ________________________________________________________\n";
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cout << BLOCK2[i].name << "    " << BLOCK2[i].num << "    " << BLOCK2[i].date << endl;

    }
    cout << "\n ________________________________________________________\n";
    char temp[M];
    int count;
    while (strcmp(temp, "exit")) {
        cout << "\nВведите фамилию: "; 
        cin >> temp;
        count = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (strcmp(BLOCK2[i].date, temp) == 0) 
            {
                cout << endl << BLOCK2[i].name << "    " << BLOCK2[i].num << endl;
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == 0) cout << endl << " Нет такой фамилии\n";
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Отладка проводилась?

Comment: Вводите фамилию, а сравниваете с датой: `strcmp(BLOCK2[i].date, temp)`

Comment: исправил, теперь выводит фамилию. но сортируя по алфавиту в 1 пункте, в таблице неправильно подбирает дату и телефон, и при вводе интересующей фамилии данные тоже неверные. сейчас прикреплю скрин

Comment: Посмотрите в своей сортировке: вы меняете только имя. А про остальные поля забыли. Дату и номер также необходимо поменять.